# AngularJS inject javascript between javascript from particular file

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I have a file called greetingmessage.ts (.whateverworks)

Inside of greetingmessage.ts:

```
{
    greeting = "Good day";
}
```

Below in index.html or script.js

```
//START JS part 1
if (1 == 1)
//END JS part 1
```

*Here, use Angular to call greetingmessage.ts and inject it between

```
//START JS part 2
else {
    greeting = "Good evening";
}
//END JS part 2
```

Comment: ok, so you have a file, and another file, and... you want to do what exactly?!?!???!!??... inject javascript into javascript, with javascript? if so, why?!

Comment: @KevinB I know it sounds funny and I can't explain it well. But is it doable?